# Install cordova on windows 10

Tags: node.js, npm-install

I have problem installing cordova on windows 10, but it worked on another system. What am I doing wrong? I'm trying to install cordova using this command:

```
npm install -g cordova
```

But I get this error:

```
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.10240
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "cordova"
npm ERR! node v5.1.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.5.0

npm ERR! error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.10240
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "cordova"
npm ERR! node v5.1.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.5.0
npm ERR! path c:\npm-debug.log.12f467e1fd39888240297f05bb2d353b
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! errno -4048
npm ERR! syscall open

npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open 'c:\npm-debug.log.12f467e1fd39888240297f05bb2d353b'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!  { [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open 'c:\npm-debug.log.12f467e1fd39888240297f05bb2d353b']
npm ERR!   errno: -4048,
npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'open',
npm ERR!   path: 'c:\\npm-debug.log.12f467e1fd39888240297f05bb2d353b' }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.
```

As you see it said run command as an administrator in last line, so I used `sudo` before my command:

```
sudo npm install -g cordova
```

and then I get this error:

```
'sudo' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

I also run this command `npm cache clean` 
But I get the same error.

**Update:**

I run node as an administrator but I get this error:

```
C:\Windows\system32>npm install -g ionic
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.10240
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "ionic"
npm ERR! node v5.1.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.3.12

npm ERR! error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
```

What am I doing wrong? Is this problem related to my OS or what?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: run the node.js command prompt as administrator by right clicking on it. Does that work? I tested it on my machine with Windows 10/ all updates no problem.

Comment: Thanks so much i tried that but i got another error. I updated my question. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows does not have sudo command, try right click your cmd application and use run as administrator option.

Additional info: https://technet.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/cc947813(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: Upvote, thank you so much, your answer was helpful, but it does not solved my problem.

Comment: check this topic to get a solution to your last problem https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/7672

Answer (score 1):

Try updating npm.

```
 npm install npm -g --ca=null
 npm config set ca=""
```